# select smallest occurrences of a column value

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling to get the following from the following table:

Original:

```
+--------+------------+-------+
| type   | variety    | price |
+--------+------------+-------+
| apple  | gala       |  2.79 | 
| apple  | gala       |  2.99 | 
| apple  | gala       |  3.45 | 
| apple  | fuji       |  0.24 | 
| apple  | limbertwig |  2.87 | 
| orange | valencia   |  3.59 | 
| orange | navel      |  9.36 | 
| pear   | bradford   |  6.05 | 
| pear   | bartlett   |  2.14 | 
| cherry | bing       |  2.55 | 
| cherry | chelan     |  6.33 | 
+--------+------------+-------+
```

What i really want:

```
+--------+------------+-------+
| type   | variety    | price |
+--------+------------+-------+
| apple  | gala       |  2.79 | 
| apple  | fuji       |  0.24 | 
| apple  | limbertwig |  2.87 | 
+--------+------------+-------+
```

So i basically want to be able to select all the apple types, but the lowest of each price.

How can I achieve this in using mysql queries?

Comment: This is such a basic thing, you really need to read a tutorial, not come here for every little thing.

Comment: How can you possibly say you are struggling. Face palm

Comment: @Drew Thanks for the feedback

Comment: You need to exhibit effort.

Comment: @Drew With this being a side project and working on it at 11:30pm on a Friday I do find it difficult to grasp some fundamental aspects of languages I've been learning on and off for about a month, maybe an hour or so a week. I have to be honest I am guilty of taking advantage and asking for help on a site full of people that are so forthcoming with help. It just means that I can concentrate on the bulk of my work. Comments like yours are neither constructive or helpful mind you.

Comment: If they get you or others to take pause before they post, then they are helpful.

Comment: Btw I have spent countless hours trying to get people removed from question bans. Anyone else try that? Ask the mods

Comment: To be fair i actually have to agree with you. Food for thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT type, variety, MIN(price) AS price
FROM yourTable
WHERE type = 'apple'
GROUP BY type, variety
```

Comment: I was annoyingly close, i just had the where and group on opposite sides. Thanks Barmar!

Comment: That's ridiculous. Can't you just read a tutorial or the MySQL documentation to see the correct order of clauses? Is SO really meant to be a substitute for reading?

Comment: Barmar, then why did you answered in first case?

Comment: @Rahul Because sometimes it's easier to just write a trivial answer than try to get the OP to show his work.